# Grafana graph bars uneven

Tags: grafana

I  wanted to show the number and status of Redmine bugs per day through Grafana. My X-axis is time, and as time goes on, my bar graph is sometimes uneven, and I don't know what's going on. Does anyone know how to do to make my bar graph even?

[image]

My SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(created_on, "1400m") AS time_sec,
  count(*) as value,
  is2.name
FROM issues i 
left join issue_statuses is2  on is2.id = i.status_id 
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(created_on) and to_days(now())-to_days(created_on)<7 
group by time_sec,is2.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dashboard time range has `To`: `now` - so, that's current time.

Use `now/d` in `To` - that's end of current day (and also `now-7d/d` will be good `From` in this case).

Comment: I am sorry that my SQL and Grafana are not very skilled.I have understood your general meaning. How should I modify it when it is applied to my case.I think ```now/d``` is in elasticsearch.how could I show ```now/d``` in my sql?

Comment: @henryCYZP that's not SQL. That's Grafana dashboard time range - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/time-range-controls/